# Extract a list of booked people using Query formula

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a event list where it's info being collected from the web form. Sometimes people click submit and are likely to get duplicates.

Sometimes people dont remember whether they submitted already, so some may resubmit.

Sometime people cancel the event and again book that was previously cancelled.

Sometimes people simply Cancel and submit for fun

Hence I need to find a way to efficiently retrieve the list of bookings those are latest.

**The list is arranged as they are submitted and hence the last one is the most recent submissions and is considered for processing.**

[Here is the link for testing purposes](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S3eRzcCFGeGFfihxftDZLW-bdY_sSUpO0wyIBtHH9RA/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

In the expected output you see that last booking is considered (**Mark**) and there are no duplicates and the cancelled events are eliminated (**Clay Dunn, Malcolm etc**). rebookings are considered even if they are previously cancelled (**Myrtle Todd**)

I have tried with

Answer (score 1):

Based on this data in Sheet1:

[image]

Try this on another sheet, cell `A1` (it does not rely on your helper column `B` for any `sort`):

```
=arrayformula(
{Sheet1!B2:F2;
query(
iferror(
vlookup(unique(lower(Sheet1!F3:F)),{query({Sheet1!F3:F,row(Sheet1!F3:F),Sheet1!B3:F},"where Col1 is not null order by Col1,Col2 desc",0)},{3,4,5,6,7,2},)
,),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col2 contains 'Booking' order by Col6 ",0)
})
```

[image]

Or if you don't want the row numbers in the helper column:

```
=arrayformula(
{Sheet1!C2:E2,"";
query(
iferror(
vlookup(unique(lower(Sheet1!F3:F)),{query({Sheet1!F3:F,row(Sheet1!F3:F),Sheet1!C3:F},"where Col1 is not null order by Col1,Col2 desc",0)},{3,4,5,6,2},)
,),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col1 contains 'Booking' order by Col5 ",0)
})
```

[image]

It uses `query`, `vlookup` to get the latest record for each value in Col F, then omits anything but 'Booking'.

Comment: I found the issue. The countifs were not ingoring non "Booking". Amended.

Comment: No Still not. See that I must not get 4 Booking Malcolm since 12 Cancelling Malcolm is present.

Comment: Updated just now. Using `query` and `vlookup`.

Comment: When you implement it in your sheet, remember to delete `Sheet1!A19:E24` otherwise you'll get incorrect results. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S3eRzcCFGeGFfihxftDZLW-bdY_sSUpO0wyIBtHH9RA/edit#gid=0&range=A19:E24

Answer (score 1):

please try:

`=SORT(SORTN(SORT(A3:E16,1,),2^99,2,5,1))`

Notes:

[SORTN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624/sortn?hl=en)

[article](https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com/2018/10/16/get-maximum-values-and-delete-duplicates-with-sortn-function/)

---

Filters are needed to be applied after SORTN to exclude last cancelled results. I suggest using query for this:

`=QUERY(SORT(SORTN(SORT(A3:E16,1,),2^99,2,5,1)),"select * where Col2 != 'Cancelling'")`

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qA_dlaFL3FQQdPKOBZtNaZ6k1x0Iv3AiQoHwtPSQO70/copy

Comment: Thanks a lot Max. I wonder why it displays the Cancelled ones as well. Malcolm has cancelled and his name should not have been in his entry, I have pasted the result in the G18 columns.

Comment: Cell C14 in yellow which is supposed to exclude Malcolm

Comment: @code-guy, if U add a filtter, my 2-nd formula from answer, cancelled will go.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K5bycFs.png all are Booking and if I add filter to it, its of no use, and the cancelled doesnt appear for filtering Malcolm must not be included https://pasteboard.co/K5byPjY.png

Comment: @CodeGuy, hi, I've noticed, for your logic you'll need to apply filter after `SORTN`, please see in edited answer